# Kakfa installation on-premise for POC and Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking into Kafka POC. Our goal is to have on-premise self managed Kafka. I was wondering what would be the best option to install Kafka

1. https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart (this is what we did install so far)
2. or should look into Confluent Platform On-premise option?

Also for option #1 I am trying to figure out to install schema registry , Any suggestion which schema registry software I can use with option # 1? (most of the google search are showing schema registry information about Confluent)

Thanks
Dhru

Comment: Voting to close as seeking off-site resources. Confluent Platform **includes** Apache Kafka (from the first link). There **are** other Schema Registries, but they mostly all copy features from the (free, open-source) Confluent one and all connect to the same ***Apache*** Kafka (there is no such thing as Confluent Kafka)

Comment: so do you recommend is it better to use Kafka downloaded from Confluent site is better for POC (since it has more features out of the box) than Apache site ?

Comment: Neither is better. Again, Confluent re-packages Kafka (as does Cloudera, Lenses.io, Aiven, Amazon MSK, and other hosting providers). It doesn't add features to it unless you pay for enterprise model. You can mix and match external components as you wish

Comment: Thank you. just to confirm "Neither is better"? so any other better option available for Kafka ?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. They all provide the same installation of Kafka and asking for recommendations is off-topic for Stackoverflow as written in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic